# Make Python Think It's Being Executed in Another Folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script saved in a directory. When I run it from its folder it works as expected. However, when I run it through an interface (Unraid's User Script plug-in's "Run Script" button) it fails.

While troubleshooting I found that the command `os.system("pwd")` returns the script's directory when I run it from the directory, but `\root` when ran through the interface.

The script is failing as imported modules are looking for files in the directory the script is in.

I'm unable to change the modules, but is there a way to make the script think it is running in a specific directory regardless of where it is executed?

Comment: use `os.chdir()`

Comment: In general, writing code that assumes it'll be run in a given working directory is a bug, and you should fix the code to no longer make that assumption. For example, you can generate paths relative to `__file__`, or update `sys.path` explicitly to change the search location used for `import`s

Comment: BTW, it's almost certainly `/root` not `\root` being returned: unraid is Linux-based, Linux uses forward slashes as path separators.

Comment: You should create a script to run the desired script for you : 
    
    os.chdir(desired_directory)
    
    os.system('python your_script_that_needs_change_dir.py')

Answer (score 0):

To change the directory from within the script, make a call to `chdir` function from the `os` module. That is, add the following to the header of your script, before importing any modules,

```
import os
os.chdir('<path/to/modules>')
```

where `<path/to/modules>` must be replaced by the actual path to the modules you want to load.

Preferrably, if your problem is just a matter of importing modules from the directory the script is living in, you can append the path using the `sys` module. That is,

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<path/to/modules>')
```